# How to switch between ViewController inside ContainerView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've added a container view inside another ViewController. From this, I dont really know how to do to swith between ViewController inside the ContainerView.

The container view:

[image: container view]

The default ViewController inside the ContainerView (with storyboard id "firstView"):
[image]

I've a last ViewController (with storyboard id "secondView")

From this, how can I do to switch between firstView and secondView inside my Container View ? How can I get an outlet for the ContainerView, firstView and secondView ? If this is not the right way to dos this, can someone help me out to achieve what I want ?

(I already checked the apple's documentation and didn't find what I need :( )

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "switch"? Do you want to replace firstView with secondView, or do you want to push to it (it looks like firstView is in a navigation controller)?

Comment: That's it: I want to replace firstView with secondView but with the "push" animation. And of course, secondView should be inside the Container View (and only in it)

Comment: Only in it? Do you mean not in a navigation controller? Is firstView in a navigation controller?

Comment: When I say "only in it" I mean only in the container view (I dont want the secondView to take the entire screen, only the part in ContainerView). firstView and secondVew are both UIViewController

Comment: You still didn't answer my question about the navigation controller. Is FirstView embedded in a navigation controller so that you can do a push, or are you trying to do a push like animation without a navigation controller?

Comment: Im trying to do a push like animation without a navigation controller

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the controller's view to the container view.

```
[controller.containerView addSubview: othercontroller.view]
```

Comment: The problem is how can I "link" my container view from storyboard to the variable controller ?